# How to make fields in QoR model readonly?

Tags: go, qor

I have a data model:

```
type Epg struct {
    gorm.Model
    Uri     string `gorm:";not null;unique"`
    Prefix  string `gorm:"size:64;not null;default:''"`
    Etag    string
    Updated time.Time
    Status  bool `gorm:"default:true"`
}
```

I publish this data model in menu:

```
EpgResource := Admin.AddResource(&models.Epg{}, &admin.Config{Menu: []string{"Content"}})
```

Now I can view and edit data via QoR Admin panel. But I want to make values `Etag`, `Updated`, `Status` to be readonly because they are updated by the system.

If I try to make this fields readonly according [documentation](https://doc.getqor.com/metas/hidden-readonly.html):

```
EpgResource.Meta(&admin.Meta{Name: "Etag", Type: "Readonly"})
```

I got an error. Is it possible to make some fields in data model visible but readonly? How to do that?

Error log trace.

> 2017/04/25 01:16:04 Finish [GET] /admin/epgs Took 19.59ms
>   /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:433
>   /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:536
>   /usr/local/go/src/text/template/exec.go:668
>   /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:302
>   /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:434
>   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:515
>   /home/rns/golang/src/github.com/qor/admin/func_map.go:1051
>   /home/rns/golang/src/github.com/qor/admin/func_map.go:220
>   /home/rns/golang/src/github.com/qor/admin/func_map.go:236
>   /home/rns/golang/src/github.com/qor/admin/func_map.go:393
>   got error when render form template for Etag(Readonly): haven't found form
>   template for meta Etag

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message, rather than an approximation?

Comment: I've extended message with detail log trace. There is a big golang stack trace too. Not sure about posting it here instead of github.

Comment: @Roman Shishkin this is the place to ask such questions and post associated info, Github should be for issues with QOR itself.

Answer (score 1):

That particular error is being caused by `qor` not finding a template file at `.../metas/form/Etag.tmpl`, which is presumably needed to actually render the `Etag` to the form.  (You can make the template render a readonly/static element rather than an input)

Answer (score 0):

`EpgResource.Meta(&admin.Meta{Name: "Etag", Type: "Readonly"})` would work only on darwin (Mac) machines. But, not on linux machines.

Do the following:

```golang
EpgResource.Meta(&admin.Meta{Name: "Etag", Type: "readonly"})
```

I hope this helps.

Reference: https://doc.getqor.com/admin/metas/hidden-readonly.html#readonly